# Problem with aws Lambda function and postgres DB

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In this day I have a problem with aws lambda. I need to search in a RDS postgres db by passing to lambda a username, but during every test event it return:

```
"{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 070f76a4-41c6-40d1-8ef2-0a84d9c04af0 Process exited before completing request"
}"
```

In particular this is the stack returnes:

> START RequestId: 070f76a4-41c6-40d1-8ef2-0a84d9c04af0 Version: $LATEST
>   2019-03-31T12:32:19.572Z  070f76a4-41c6-40d1-8ef2-0a84d9c04af0    TypeError:
>   Path must be a string. Received undefined
>       at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
>       at Object.join (path.js:1236:7)
>       at Object.module.exports.getFileName (/var/task/node_modules/pgpass/lib/helper.js:61:16)
>       at module.exports (/var/task/node_modules/pgpass/lib/index.js:10:23)
>       at Connection. (/var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:110:9)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Connection.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at Socket. (/var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:125:12)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7) END RequestId: 070f76a4-41c6-40d1-8ef2-0a84d9c04af0 REPORT RequestId:
>   070f76a4-41c6-40d1-8ef2-0a84d9c04af0  Duration: 583.72 ms Billed
>   Duration: 600 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 35 MB
>   RequestId: 070f76a4-41c6-40d1-8ef2-0a84d9c04af0 Process exited before
>   completing request

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

global.fetch = require('node-fetch');

var Pool = require('pg').Pool;

const psql = new Pool ({

host: '',
user: '',
password: '',
database: 'metadata',
port: 5432
})

function searchUser(username){

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    psql.query("SELECT username FROM utilitator where username LIKE '%$1%'", [username], {

        onSucces: function(res){
            resolve(res.rows);
        },
        onFailure: function(err){
            resolve("err");
        },
    });
});
}

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
//var body = JSON.parse(event.body);

var username = event.username;

var response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "isBase64Encoded": false,
    "body": {},
}

try{
    var result = await searchUser(username).then((result) => {
        return result;
    });

    var statusCode = 200;
    var body = result;
    if(result == "err"){
        statusCode = 400;
        body = "user not found";
    }

    response.statusCode = statusCode;
    response.body = body;

    callback(null,response);
}
catch(e){
    callback(e,{
        "isBase64Encoded": false,
        "headers": {},
        "body": "err",
        "statusCode": 501
    });
}
};
```

I expect that Lambda return all user in db that have a similar username that I have passed.

Answer (score 0):

I was browsing through the [node-postgres docs](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries) and I did not find any reference to `onSuccess` and `onFailure` events, but only `err` and `res` objects in the callback (but I may have overlooked it):

```
client.query(text, values, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.stack)
  } else {
    console.log(res.rows[0])
    // { name: 'brianc', email: 'brian.m.carlson@gmail.com' }
  }
})
```

However, it also supports a promise version, meaning you don't have to promifisy it yourself:

```
try {
  const res = await pool.query(text, values)
  console.log(res.rows[0])
  // { name: 'brianc', email: 'brian.m.carlson@gmail.com' }
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err.stack)
}
```

This means your `searchUser` function should look like this:

```
const searchUser = username => {
  return await psql.query('SELECT username FROM utilitator where username LIKE $1', [`%${username}%`])
};
```

Finally, on your handler, since you are already using Node 8, you should not mix promises and callbacks together. Simply return the body in a stringified JSON inside your response object, like this (error handling omitted for the sake of simplicity):

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  //const body = JSON.parse(event.body);

  const username = event.username;

  const result = await searchUser(username)

  if (result == "err") {
    return {
      "statusCode": 404,
      "isBase64Encoded": false,
      "body": JSON.stringify({message: 'User not found'}),
    }
  }
  return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "isBase64Encoded": false,
    "body": JSON.stringify(result),
  }

};
```

Comment: Ok i tried and didn't accept await in searchUser, but without it work. The only problem is that in the body is empty

Comment: Well, that's obviously another problem now. You don't get an exception anymore. If the body is null it's very likely that either you have a bug in your query or your table is empty.

Comment: There was a bug in your query. I have edited my answer accordingly. For your convenience, here's how you should invoke your query `return await psql.query('SELECT username FROM utilitator where username LIKE $1', [\`%${username}%\`])`